# Change signup field error message and field color

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

we are currently implementing a membership page. I hope the color of the field will be red if there is an error, but I don't know what to do. What should I add to my code so that it's possible?

```
 <form method="post" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

```
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="{{field.html_name }}" id="{{ field.id_for_lable }}" class="form-control" type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" value="{{ field.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
            placeholder="{{field.label}}">
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <label class="control-label" for="{{ field.id_for_lable }}" style="color: #c13b2a;"><b>{{ error }}</b></label>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

     <div class="bbb" style="text-align: center">
      <button type="submit">가입하기</button><br>
     </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the build in form from Django itself? You can render your forms beautifully with something like crispy forms and the Django forms.Form comes with an error handling. So no need to invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add stye if condition

```
<input ... {% if field.errors %} style={"color":"red"} {% endif %}>
```

or add a class if condition

```
<input ... class =".. {% if field.errors %} text-red {% endif %}">
```